# ダウンロードした tbz ファイルが tar コマンドで解凍できない

Tags: tar

以下のページを参考にRaspberry Pi3 (raspbian lite)にQt Embedded環境を作ろうとしているのですが、

http://wiki.qt.io/Raspberry_Pi_Beginners_Guide

> クロスコンパイルツールチェーンをダウンロードする：
>
> ```
> wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/sl919ly0q79m1e6/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf.tbz
> (or at http://de.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_rfidmonitor/downloads/crosscompilation-resources/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf.tbz)
> tar -xf gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf.tbz
> ```

保存したtbzファイルがtarコマンドで解凍できずに止まってしまいました。

**エラー**

```
$ tar -xf gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf.tbz 
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

どなたか解凍する方法を伝授して頂けないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

最初の URL（Dropbox の方）は 404 ですね。
二個目の URL（SourceForge の方）も、GET すると HTML ページが返ってくる URL だと思います。
どちらにしろ、`wget` した物はアーカイブファイルではなく、HTML なのではないかと推測します。
`file gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf.tbz` や `cat -v gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf.tbz` で内容を確認出来ます。

対策としては、SourceForge の方にブラウザでアクセスすると、ダウンロード用の URL がありますので、それを `wget` することが考えられます。
例えば、`https://osdn.net/frs/g_redir.php?m=netix&f=%2Frfidmonitor%2Fcrosscompilation-resources%2Fgcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf.tbz` といった URL です。
URL に `&` が含まれていますから、`wget` に渡す時にはクォートする必要があります。

---

（個人的には得体の知れない URL と感じましたので、コピペ可能なコマンドの記載は控え、リンクにもしていません。Wiki の内容ですから、裏を取りながらの作業が必要かと思います）